# Is shutting off water supply necessary if no longer using the water dispenser and ice maker?

Tags: refrigerator

Is it necessary to shut off the water supply on a GE refrigerator if no longer using the water dispenser or ice maker.  Ice maker has been shut off
GE Model # GSS25IYNWHFS

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

No, it is not necessary.

But if you have no intention to use the ice or water any time soon then turning off the water supply (i.e., outside the refrigerator) prevents a mechanical failure or human intervention from resulting in a flood inside (ice maker) or outside (water dispenser) the refrigerator.

Comment: Thank you very much